# Magento2 How to filter Product collection by Stock (Get only In stock products)

Tags: magento2, php, catalog, magento2.3.3, inventory

I want to filter product collection by stock and get only In stock products. I have tried multiple ways and followed multiple stack solutions but nothing works as expected.
I am using the Smartwave Porto theme. In the Porto theme, there's is a feature for showing the latest products on the front end. So, I want to filter the latest products collection by stock.

**Block File Code:**

```
public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();
        $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        if(!$category_id) {
            $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
        if(isset($category) && $category) {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite() 
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        } else {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        }

        $collection->getSelect()
                ->order('created_at','desc')
                ->limit($count);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }
```

**PHTML code:**

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

I used the below code in the phtml as well as block file as per @davidas answer, but not working:

```
$_productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
$_productCollection = $_productCollection
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 1])
->load();
```

**Note: MSI feature is used in Magento.**

**Magento version 2.3.3-p1**

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create();
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
$collection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('from' => $start ,'to' => $end))->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku'))
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory_stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    )->joinTable('cataloginventory_stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('stock_status' => 'is_in_stock'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
    ->addFieldToFilter('stock_status', ['eq' => 1])
->load();
```

Comment: @Davidas I tried this but not working.

Comment: update your question with code. so we will check

Comment: @Davidas please check updaed question

Comment: change this code in your template file $_productCollection->getSelect()->joinField   and check

Comment: Error filtering template: Unrecognized method 'joinField()' this error is showing.

Comment: This is working